Executing stored procedure from C# fails with linked server but works in SSMS
We are using C# to execute a stored procedure where this stored procedure uses EXECUTE AS to call data from a linked server.
ALTER PROCEDURE [NS_TEST].[SP_GET_DATA_TEST]
    @P_VALUE NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
WITH EXECUTE AS 'PROXY_USER'
AS
BEGIN
    -- select from linked server
END

When connected to the server in SSMS as a user, it works as expected and pulls data from the linked server.
When executing this in a C# application with a connection string that connects with a as the same user as SSMS before, it fails with being unable to access the linked server.

The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "SERVER_NAME" reported
an error. Authentication failed.

Connection string with SQL Authentication

Server=SERVER_NAME.domain.com;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User
ID=USERNAME;Password=***********;Encrypt=False;Trust Server
Certificate=True

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand(NS_TEST.SP_GET_DATA_TEST", connection))
{
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P_VALUE", "TESTVALUE");
    
    connection.Open();
    await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
}

We've tried both Microsoft.Data.SqlClient and System.Data.SqlClient with the same result.
Is there a reason that this will work via SSMS and not via the C# code?

Are the users connecting in SSMS and connection string same? (and it is not windows authentication in both?)

And since it is linked server, you don't want to directly connect there but use this SP? (asking just because I have experienced problems with MS SQL's linked servers)

What are the account settings on the actual linked server object? The account you are using is only in context of the server you are connecting to. The account in the linked server configuration are the credentials that will be used on the other, linked server.

Check log files with SSMS.  The log files are in the explorer under management.  The log files should show the group and user that is being used to connect.  The issue is with the connection string which is not shown.  Authentication is failing so the permissions are not allowed with the parameters in the connection string.  When you connect using SSMS on the login screen what type credentials are being used (Windows or SQL)?  If windows the connection string should use Integrated Security = True.

I've added the connection string we are using. The SQL Server logs just shows the same error message and the same for Windows server logs
